# Can CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ever be null?

Tags: .net, cultureinfo

Can CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ever be null?

A null value would crash my program, which I don't want. So I'm asking, to be safe, do I need to do?

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ?? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It definitely looks like it's guaranteed to be non-`null`:

> The culture is a property of the executing thread. This read-only
>   property is equivalent to retrieving the `CultureInfo` object returned
>   by the `Thread.CurrentCulture` property.

[`Thread.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) throws an exception if you try to set it to `null`, so it's logical to assume that having a non-`null` value is an invariant.

Apart from this, `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` gives the algorithm that determines its initial value:

> #### How a Thread's Culture Is Determined
>
> When a thread is started, its culture is initially determined as
>   follows:
>
> - By retrieving the culture that is specified by the `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` property in the application domain in
>     which the thread is executing, if the property value is not `null`.
> - By calling the Windows `GetUserDefaultLocaleName` function.

Again, this doesn't leave open the option of a `null` value.

Answer (score 6):

No, non-null is guaranteed. This is the implementation of `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentCulture` which is returned directly from `CultureInfo.CurentCulture`  (via ILSpy):

```
// System.Threading.Thread
public CultureInfo CurrentUICulture
{
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    get
    {
        if (this.m_CurrentUICulture == null)
        {
            return CultureInfo.UserDefaultUICulture;
        }
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = null;
        if (!Thread.nativeGetSafeCulture(this, Thread.GetDomainID(), true, ref cultureInfo) || cultureInfo == null)
        {
            return CultureInfo.UserDefaultUICulture;
        }
        return cultureInfo;
    }
    // setter following
```

So if `m_CurrentUICulture` is null it will return `UserDefaultUICulture`.

This is the source:

```
internal static CultureInfo UserDefaultUICulture
{
    get
    {
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.s_userDefaultUICulture;
        if (cultureInfo == null)
        {
            CultureInfo.s_userDefaultUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InitUserDefaultUICulture();
            CultureInfo.s_userDefaultUICulture = cultureInfo;
        }
        return cultureInfo;
    }
}
```

As you can see, if even that is null `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` will be returned.

Comment: the question was about CurrentCulture, not CurrentUICulture, although the situation there is most probably very similar.

Comment: @Knagis: Yes, i've skipped a step accidentally, but it's valid anyway. Edited  the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the .NET source, it will throw an error if anybody tries to set it to `null` - so no, it cannot be `null`.

```
/// <summary>Gets or sets the culture for the current thread.</summary>
/// <returns>A <see cref="T:System.Globalization.CultureInfo" /> representing the culture for the current thread.</returns>
/// <exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The property is set to a neutral culture. Neutral cultures cannot be used in formatting and parsing and therefore cannot be set as the thread's current culture.</exception>
/// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The property is set to null.</exception>
/// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
/// <PermissionSet>
///   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Flags="ControlThread" />
/// </PermissionSet>
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public CultureInfo CurrentCulture
{
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
get
{
    if (AppDomain.IsAppXModel())
    {
        return CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoForUserPreferredLanguageInAppX() ?? this.GetCurrentCultureNoAppX();
    }
    return this.GetCurrentCultureNoAppX();
}
[__DynamicallyInvokable, SecuritySafeCritical]
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, ControlThread = true)]
set
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    }
    CultureInfo.nativeSetThreadLocale(value.SortName);
    value.StartCrossDomainTracking();
    this.m_CurrentCulture = value;
}
}
```

Comment: That's no evidence. The culture field could be set directly. Actually, if you look at the getter there are multiple places where the null is possible. Also, you're showing the instance property `CurrentCulture`and not the static as requested.