# UnauthorizedAccessException when testing a method creating a SolidColorBrush

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, exception, windows-phone-8

I've seen a couple of threads about this on the Internet, but I feel like none of them apply to my situation... Either that, or I just simply haven't understood a thing from them (which is likely).

The thing is: I'm writing a test for a converter method, that "converts" an Enum to an appropriate SolidColorBrush.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    Brush result = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

    if (value != null)
    {
        switch ((InstallationStatus)value)
        {
            case InstallationStatus.Draft:
                result = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
                break;
            case InstallationStatus.Ready:
                result = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                break;
            case InstallationStatus.Uploaded:
                result = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                break;
            case InstallationStatus.Error:
                result = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works just fine on its own, when called from the app's view.
I also have a test method, that basically does this:

```
InstallationStatusBrushConverter converter = new InstallationStatusBrushConverter();
object result = converter.Convert(null, null, null, null);
```

The test method calls Convert, which tries to instantiate the result field, but the UnauthorizedAccessException gets thrown...
Does anyone have an idea of what's going on here?

Comment: I guess the test method is not executed in the UI thread. Anything UI related can only be created/accessed in the UI thread.

Comment: Is this test method run on a background thread? Is the error message looks like `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.`?

Comment: As an aside, is there a specific reason that you are creating _new_ brushes?  How will these brushes be disposed so that you don't leak GDI handles?  Instead, you can just return the built in brushes:  `result = Brushes.Red`.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway There is no `Brushes` class in WP, also there are no GDI handles in WP. It's quite safe to create new Brushes. :)

Comment: @yasen - Thanks.  I wasn't sure if that was the case for WP or not.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - I don't know, don't ask me, I'm not the one who wrote those converters ;D

Comment: @kennyzx - the tests are in a separate test project, so I imagine they are run on a separate thread...
Well, I guess I'll have to learn about and experiment with dispatchers.

Answer (score 0):

[Can CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ever be null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359141/can-cultureinfo-currentculture-ever-be-null)

Possible source of error - `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` should not be null. Instead, in function parameters, change `culture` parameter to `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`

Comment: I suppose it doesn't really matter if you don't use that object yourself. In other converter unit tests I pass null as the culture parameter and they works just fine, so it seems like it's not used anywhere else.